# Google Analytics: Paid Search Visits higher than Clicks

Tags: google-analytics, search-engine, web-traffic

So, I understand there is a possibility that paid search clicks recorded in the search engines might be higher than the visits GA records from paid Search, but has anyone experienced the opposite?  I am seeing visits from Paid Search traffic **higher** than the amount of clicks recorded.  I am looking at overall visits from Paid Search, not unique visits.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when your AdWords campaigns have **acquired visitors** that keep **coming back through direct access** or referral after a click on an AdWords link.

Their recurring visits in direct access remains attributed to AdWords.

This typically occurs on news sites, real estate sites, and every site where people keep coming in again and again from day to day.

You can look further at "Campaign Tracking and AdWords Integration" on the [GA Conversion University course](http://www.google.com/intl/en/analytics/iq.html)